# Old School Holy Avenger in 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e

I have a vague memory from the old D&D days that a `Holy Avenger` sword was a lot more powerful than the version in 4e (or many of the AD&D versions for that matter)

Is there a 4e mechanic that allows for the Old-School Holy Avenger in the hands of a `Paladin`:

- +5 to attack
- 100% resistance to magic (personal only)
- acts as a `Flaming Sword` (but radiant rather than fire damage,
  considering)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is going to give you resistance to magic in 4e; it doesn't even have the concept. There *is* a radiant weapon enhancement that allows you to convert all the damage you do with the weapon to radiant damage, as well as adding an additional item bonus to damage whenever you do radiant damage, which would be pretty close to the rest of what you're looking for.

From Adventurer's Vault:

> **Radiant Weapon**
>
> lvl 15 +3, lvl 20 +4, lvl 25 +5, lvl 30 +6
>
> Weapon: Any | Enhancement: Attack rolls & damage rolls
>
> Critical +1d6 radiant damage per plus
>
> Property: When this weapon is used to deal radiant damage, add its enhancement bonus as an item bonus to damage rolls
>
> Power(At-Will, Radiant): Free Action. All damage dealt by this weapon is radiant damage. Another free action returns the damage to normal.

Comment: I have found powers that give temporary resistance to damage, a few even give resistance to all kinds of damage.  This is a radiant version of a flaming sword, which isn't very much like what i had in mind.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the key difference is that he's looking for 100% magic resistance as well. Unfortunately, that kind of power doesn't mesh with 4e. Attack powers are no longer classified into magical and non-magical, as they were in 3e, and complete immunity to a certain damage type is considered far too powerful for even a high-level 4e item. The closest equivalent ability in a 4e weapon is resist 30 to one element (e.g. Chill Wind weapon, or Icingdeath).

Comment: Yes, but what element? "Magic" doesn't deal any one type of damage consistently, and resist all is *way* too good to slap onto what's already one of the better weapons (especially if the players might run Radiant Mafia). As I said, if plain old Radiant Weapon doesn't cut it, the OP probably needs to design his own artifact.

Answer (score 1):

They actually do have the Holy Avenger (albeit differently) in 4e!

> Holy Avenger Level 25+ Rare
>
> The most prized weapon of any paladin.
>
> Lvl 25    +5  625,000 gp      Lvl
> 30    +6  3,125,000 gp
>
> Weapon: Axe, hammer or heavy blade
>
> Enhancement Bonus: attack rolls and damage rolls
>
> Critical: +1d6 radiant damage per plus, and you can spend a healing
> surge
>
> Special: A holy avenger can be used as a holy symbol. It adds its
> enhancement bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls and the extra
> damage granted by its property (if applicable) when used in this
> manner. You do not gain your weapon proficiency bonus to an attack
> roll when using a holy avenger as an implement. Property
>
> Your radiant powers deal 1d10 extra radiant damage when used through
> the weapon. Power Daily (Minor Action)
>
> You and each ally within 10 squares of you gain a +5 power bonus to
> fortitude, Reflex, and Will until the end of your next turn.

I'd also suggest Vigilant Blade for the holy concentrated weapon feel with more damage focus available at a lower level.

> Vigilant Blade Level 4+ Uncommon
>
> Set with the symbol of an upright gauntlet with an unblinking eye in
> its palm, this blade bursts into burning white light in the hands of
> one sworn to bring justice to the wicked.
>
> Lvl 4  +1  840 gp      Lvl
> 19    +4  105,000 gp Lvl 9    +2  4,200 gp        Lvl 24  +5  525,000 gp Lvl
> 14    +3  21,000 gp       Lvl 29  +6  2,625,000 gp
>
> Weapon: Heavy blade or light blade
>
> Enhancement Bonus: attack rolls and damage rolls
>
> Critical: +1d8 fire and radiant damage per plus Property
>
> Paladins and avengers can use this weapon as an implement for paladin
> or avenger powers and paladin or avenger paragon path powers.
>
> Power (Minor Action)
>
> The weapon casts bright light out to 4 squares until you end this
> effect as a minor action.
>
> Power Encounter (Immediate Reaction)
>
> Trigger: You use this power when an ally adjacent to you is attacked
> by an enemy adjacent to you.
>
> Effect: You switch places with the ally, and the target grants combat
> advantage to you until the end of your next turn.

Comment: -1 for your opinion? Holy Blade inherently answers the question and Vigilant Blade was offered as well because it had a similar feel but mechanically fit better within 4e (I.E. being able to use it as an implement).

Comment: holy avenger does not answer the question as it's existence is acknowledged and put aside here.

Comment: Point taken. Also What specifically are you doing (in edits) to space the lines within a block quote so its not a garble of text?

Comment: see the edit summary, use the markdown for quotes > rather than html tags. If you click the ? next to the edit box there is a summary of what markdown is available, it's incredibly useful in properly formatting stuff here.

Comment: I found both the 4e "Holy Avenger" and "Vigilant Blade" which is what caused me to ask this question.  I don't see much of a difference between these and much lower level weapons.  There isn't any "AHA!" moment to them that a paladin requires dramatically

Answer (score 1):

The closest mechanical equivalent to what you describe is the [Chill Wind Weapon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=856). Modify it as follows to create something close to the oldschool magic-proof Holy Avenger:

> **HOLY AVENGER**
>   Lvl 25  +5  625,000 gp
>
> **Weapon:** Heavy blade
>   **Enhancement bonus:** attack rolls and damage rolls
>   **Critical:** +1d6 fire damage per plus and ongoing 20 radiant damage (save ends)
>
> **Property**
>   You gain resist 30 arcane.
>
> **Power (Radiant) ♦ (Free Action)**
>   All damage dealt by this weapon is radiant damage.  Another free action returns the damage to normal.

Answer (score 0):

The radiant weapon mentioned in Oblivious Sage's answer is a great start. I would use that and make the following changes:

- Make it deal fire and radiant damage (since it's holy fire that burns evil).
- The damage resistance is best converted like this:

> Power(Encounter): Free action. You gain resist 10(paragon)/15(epic) all until the end of your next turn.

Alternatively, if you want an always-on DR effect, you could use this:

> Property: This weapon grants a paladin that wields it resist all equal to the weapon's enhancement bonus.